# How to include Java BDD in a Bluemix build and deploy pipeline?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, bdd, continuous-deployment, atdd

In the team I'm involved, we are looking how we could benefit from the bluemix services to improve our actual devops process. Our technology stack is based on Java, Weblogic, Oracle. We would like that every new development contribution of a team members *once complied and verified locally* is integrated in a bluemix-powered integration area then the result automatically deployed in a "integration space" followed by the automatic execution of BDD tests and results reported.

Anyone having alrady implemented/experienced such a configuration? Or any pointers on that suject?

Regards,
Olivier.

Answer (score 0):

The scenario you describe can be fulfilled with the Bluemix DevOps Services, including Track & Plan and Deployment Pipeline. You can find details in the [Bluemix DevOps Services docs](https://new-console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/devops.html).

Stack Overflow is for technical questions, generally about coding. Your question verges into product planning information, which probably accounts for the down-votes. Those kinds of questions are best on vendor-specific forums. You can ask Bluemix product, offering, and account questions on [IBM developerWorks Answers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html).

Comment: Thanks Ralph for pointing me back toward dw. I now know I should consider StackOverflow for coding-related questions. Regards.